# Как скомбинировать несколько преобразований XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

У меня есть такой HTML файл:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>A title of the article</title>
<style type="text/css">
body {
  font-family: Helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.6;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 30px; }

body > *:first-child {
  margin-top: 0 !important; }
body > *:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0 !important; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <p>The page is an article about an article.</p>
  <p>This paragraph is not very good paragraph</p>
  <p>This paragraph is very good paragraph</p>
  <h4 id="toc_0">Page content</h4>
  <ul>
    <li>An itroduction</li>
    <li>An inline piece of code <code>select * from dual</code></li>
    <li>Buttons <kbd>OK</kbd> and <kbd>Cancel</kbd></li>
  </ul>
  <div>
    <pre>
      <code class="language-none">select * from dual
      </code>
    </pre>
  </div>

  <h4 id="toc_1">Usage</h4>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Page ID</th>
        <th>Page name</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1234</td>
        <td>Page number 1234</td>
      </tr>
      <tr> 
        <td>5678</td>
        <td>Page number 5678</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>90AB</td>
        <td>Page number 90AB</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

С ним надо проделать следующее:

1. Все теги `code` и `kbd` заменить на `span`
2. К каждому `span` добавить класс с названием того тега, который был раньше (т. е. должно получиться `<span class="code">` или `<span class="kbd">`)
3. Оставить все содержимое тега `body`, а остальное удалить.

Удалось нагуглить, как сделать все это по частям. Пункты 1 и 2 можно сделать с помощью преобразования

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="code">
        <span class="code"><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /></span>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="kbd">
        <span class="kbd"><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /></span>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Пункт 3 - с помощью

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/html/body">
        <xsl:copy-of select="node()"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text()" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Но каждое из преобразований делает только что-то свое, то есть я либо могу заменить теги, либо вырезать кусок из `body`. Попытки как-то скомбинировать два преобразования дают мусор на выходе. Кроме того, второе преобразование не вставляет класс, если он до этого был, то есть кусок

```
<code class="language-none">
```

превращается в

```
<span class="language-none">
```

В идеале конечно хотелось бы

```
<span class="language-none code">
```

Отдельно бесит, что если в исходном файле есть строка

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">`

То программа ругается на невалидный XML (ну ок, я согласен, невалидный). Но при этом после первого преобразования программа сама же вставляет ровно такую же строку в результат. Все преобразования делаю в командной строке утилитой xsltproc.

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51246055/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем, спросил на enSO, вот рабочий вариант, делает ровно то, что нужно:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="html | html/body">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="html/head"/>

    <xsl:template match="code">
        <span class="{@class} code"><xsl:apply-templates select="@*[not(local-name() = 'class')] | node()" /></span>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="kbd">
        <span class="{@class} kbd"><xsl:apply-templates select="@*[not(local-name() = 'class')] | node()" /></span>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```